# Control Template For Graphical Checkbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

on my resource i got

```
 <ControlTemplate TargetType="Label" x:Key="GraphicalCheckBox">
            <Label Name="TickImage"/>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Tag" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="TickImage" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource ContractApprovedGreen}" />
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="Tag" Value="False">
                    <Setter TargetName="TickImage" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource Close}" />
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
```

on my view i got

```
<Label x:Name="COC" Template="{StaticResource GraphicalCheckBox}" Tag="{Binding Bill20IsValid}" Width="100" Height="100" Background="Gray" />
```

when I change Bill20IsValid to `True` then `TextBox` changes to `True` but the label isn't updated to `ContractApprovedGreen` ,`ContractApprovedGreen` works fine on other code places, and I am SURE this code worked a few month ago.

why my `GraphicalCheckBox` templete wouln't work?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why Trigger doesn't work, but DataTrigger works for me:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True">
    <Setter TargetName="TickImage" Property="Background" Value="Green" />
</DataTrigger>
```